# How can i gather results from F.promise and use that

Tags: java, asynchronous, playframework, promise, future

I am using play framework for java application. I am make a async call using F.promise and I want to take the results from that call and perform some actions. How can i do this? There is a method in play called F.promise.onFailure but i can't see any methods for success . Please help.

Comment: you can use F.promise.map()

Answer (score 0):

F.promise is deprecated and play framework docs recommend to use the JDK8 CompletionStage instead.

```
public CompletionStage<Result> getSomething() {
  return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
    Object something = `your async call here`;
    return ok(something);
  }, executor);
}
```